# Monte Carlo simulation in R for Monty Hall problem not working?

Tags: r, simulation, probability, data-science

I'm writing a function in R to perform a Monte Carlo simulation for the Monty Hall problem. The function is working when the doors are not switched it `switch == FALSE`, but when I call `mean(replicate(10000, monty_hall(switch = TRUE)))`, the expected answer is about `0.66` but I actually get around `0.25`.

Here is the code to the function:

```
monty_hall = function(switch = logical()){
    doors <- c(1,2,3)
    names(doors) <- rep(c("goat", "car"), c(2,1))
    prize_door <- doors[3]

    guess <- sample(doors, 1)
    revealed_door <- sample(doors[!doors %in% c(guess, prize_door)],1)
    if(switch){
        switched_door <- sample(doors[!doors %in% c(guess, revealed_door)],1)
        prize_door == switched_door
    } else {
        prize_door == guess
        }
}
```

What changes should I make to get the correct output, which is around `0.66`?

Comment: Hint: `sample(2, 1)` won't always return the output '2'.

Comment: This isn't the issue with your code, but you don't need to use `sample()` for the switched door.  It can only be the door that is neither the guess nor the revealed door - i.e.  `doors[-c(guess, revealed_door)]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change the doors vector to characters

```
monty_hall = function(switch = logical()){
   doors <- c("1","2","3")
   names(doors) <- rep(c("goat", "car"), c(2,1))
   prize_door <- doors[3]

   guess <- sample(doors, 1)
   revealed_door <- sample(doors[!doors %in% c(guess, prize_door)],1)
   if(switch){
      switched_door <- sample(doors[!doors %in% c(guess, revealed_door)],1)
      prize_door == switched_door
   } else {
      prize_door == guess
   }
}
```

Suppose the person chose door number 1 and the prize is in door number 2, so what is left to be revealed is door number 3.

You will have `revealed_door <- sample(3,1)` and this doesn't work as you are expecting, this becomes `revealed_door <- sample(c(1,2,3),1)`

From the function documentation, just type `?sample`

> If x has length 1, is numeric (in the sense of is.numeric) and x >= 1,
>   sampling via sample takes place from 1:x. Note that this convenience
>   feature may lead to undesired behaviour when x is of varying length in
>   calls such as sample(x)

I think the easiest fix is changing to characters, but if you must use numerical values just do a check for the vector's length and return the value if it is 1, or do a sample otherwise